# Is there a way in react to find out if an image resource fails to load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, load

I have a list of images that I'm looping through and will show them in my components but I have a problem, consider some of these images won't load due to server failure, so my question is how can I provide a fallback for these images.

for example:

```
imageResourses.map(src => src ? <img src={src} /> : <FallbackImageComponent />)
```

My challenge is if an `src` property exists I show the actual image which can lead to a none desire output due to `server` failure.

So how can I show My `FallbackImageComponent` in case there was a problem with loading the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a reusable `Image` Component which will render a fallback image whenever the image is not resolved.

**Here is the sample code for `Image` component:**

```
class Image extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hasError: false
  };

  handleError = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      hasError: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return "Error Fallback Image";
    }

    return <img {...this.props} onError={this.handleError} />;
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<Image src="..." />
```

See the working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-snow-5295o?file=/src/App.js:348-660

`Note:` There may be other solutions as well. If I stumble upon them I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks Yash, That was a neat trick. Do you know `onError` is only available in `react` or it's an `html property`?

Comment: `onError` is an event present in native img. You can check it here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onerror